# If I change the size of HDFS block does the size of splits change too?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I change the size of HDFS block:

```
hadoop fs -D dfs.block.size=134217728 -put local_name remote_location
```

Does the size of splits (`mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize`) change too?

Answer (score 0):

-D dfs.block.size has no bearing on the split minsize. The "**-D dfs.block.size**" will only alter the block size for that file only.

Comment: In local_name I can specify a directory and not a file. So it will alter the block size of all files in the directory.